# Windows phone transition animation in Android

Tags: android, animation, android-animation, transition

I want to implement the transition animation available in windows phone in my android application.

The animation should look like in the video below

[News Republic Android application](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZU4j6VL2Qvg)

Where should i start from ?